# Widening a data frame by copying values from a conditionally-identified row into new columns

Tags: r

I have a data set for a meta-analysis that contains pre-test data in a set of columns, post-test data in another set of columns, and one column for condition (i.e., treatment [Condition == 1] versus control [Condition == 0]). I need to widen this data set such that I create a new set of columns for control observations' pre-test data and post-test data which is placed alongside that of the original treatment data. These data are grouped by ID. This means that I need to conditionally copy only observations that are "control" into a set of columns alongside the "treatment" observations, but within each ID group.

I know that's an obnoxious way to describe it, so here's an example of the data set I have:

```
data_before.df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                         Condition = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2),
                         Pre_M = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                         Post_M = c(90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10))
data_before.df
```

And here's what I need to get to:

```
data_after.df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                            Condition = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                            Pre_M = c(2,3,5,6,8,9),
                            Post_M = c(80,70,50,40,20,10),
                            Control_Pre_M = c(1,1,4,4,7,7),
                            Control_Post_M = c(90,90,60,60,30,30))
data_after.df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', create create two new column with 'Control' as part of the column by looping over the column that end with 'M' and subsetting the value where 'Condition' is 0, `ungroup` and `filter` out the row where 'Condition' is 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data_before.df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('M')), list(Control = ~.[Condition == 0])) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    filter(Condition != 0) %>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with('Control')), ~
             str_replace(., '(.*)_Control', 'Control_\\1'))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#     ID Condition Pre_M Post_M Control_Pre_M Control_Post_M
#  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
#1     1         1     2     80             1             90
#2     1         2     3     70             1             90
#3     2         1     5     50             4             60
#4     2         2     6     40             4             60
#5     3         1     8     20             7             30
#6     3         2     9     10             7             30
```

---

Or an option with `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(subset(data_before.df, Condition != 0), 
   subset(data_before.df, Condition == 0, 
        select = c("ID", "Pre_M", "Post_M")), by = 'ID')
```

---

Or a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_before.df)[Condition != 0][data_before.df[Condition == 0, 
   .(ID, Control_Pre_M = Pre_M, Control_Post_M = Post_M)], on  = .(ID)]
#    ID Condition Pre_M Post_M Control_Pre_M Control_Post_M
#1:  1         1     2     80             1             90
#2:  1         2     3     70             1             90
#3:  2         1     5     50             4             60
#4:  2         2     6     40             4             60
#5:  3         1     8     20             7             30
#6:  3         2     9     10             7             30
```